# Connecting the Servlet to the jsp page table

Tags: jsp, servlets

How do I connect this servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/AccountLookupServlet"})
public class AccountLookupServlet extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */


             String id = request.getParameter("id");
            String pw = request.getParameter("pw");
            System.out.println(id);
            System.out.println(pw);


            Account a1=new Account();
            a1.findDB(id);
            String an=a1.getAcctNo();
            System.out.println(an);

            String ln=a1.getCustId();
            System.out.println(ln);

            String at=a1.getType();
            System.out.println(at);


              double bal=a1.getBalance();
            System.out.println(bal);


            HttpSession ses1=request.getSession();
            ses1.setAttribute("a1", a1);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
    */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request,response);

    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if (action.equals(null)) {

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

        } 
        /* Gets single searched account from the accountLookup.jsp */
        else if (action.equals("getAcct")) {

            String acctNo = request.getParameter("accountNo");

            try {

                /* Instantiates a new Account class and sets it as a request attribute
                for use in the accountView.jsp */
                Account account = new Account(acctNo);
                request.setAttribute("account", account);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/accountView.jsp").forward(request, response);

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AccountLookupServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }

}
```

To connect to this jsp page to pull out the Customer ID, Account Number, Account Type, and Balance to appear in the table I created? The Servlet is working, the database is connected, I just need a way for the JSP page to read in the data and actually print it out.

```
<%@page import="Business.Account"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Your Account</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="chattBank.css" type="text/css">
        <style>
                #image{
                    text-align: center;
                }
                #acctForm{
                    text-align: center;
                }
                #acctTable{
                    margin-left: 645px;
                }
                #submitTable{
                    margin-left: 755px;
                }
                table{
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                }
                h4{
                    text-align: center;
                }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "image">
            <img src="bankpic.jpg" />
        </div>
        <h4>Here Is The Account You Requested</h4>
        <table border="1" width="75%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="10">Your Chatt Accounts</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td colspan="2">Customer Id</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Account Number</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Account Type</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Account Balance</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Account: </td>
                    <td colspan="2">${account.custId}</td>
                    <td colspan="2">${account.acctNo}</td>
                    <td colspan="2">${account.type}</td>
                    <td colspan="2">${account.balance}</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
                <table width="50%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <td></td>
                    <td>Click Here To Navigate To A New Page</td>
                    <td></td>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="AccountServlet?action=view&id=${customer.custId}">View All Accounts</a></td>
                    <td><a href="ManageAccounts?action=manage&id=${customer.custId}">Manage Accounts</a></td>
                    <td><a href="Logout?action=logout">Log Out</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the account Business Object: want to make sure it is correct for hooking up the accountview.jsp to connect to the account to pull out the DB the account information.

```
public class Account implements Serializable{

    private String acctNo;
    private String custId;
    private String type;
    private double balance;
    private String message;

    /**
     * No-Arg Constructor
     */
    public Account() {

    }

    /**
     * Single Arg constructor accepts one parameter
     * connects to database and builds the customers 
     * account object 
     * @param acct
     */
    public Account(String acct) throws SQLException {

        Connection connect = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE acctNo = '" + acct + "';";

        try {
            /*establishes connection and creates statement */
            connect = acctConnect();
            statement = connect.createStatement();
            result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            /*loops through the database row containing the information
            and builds the row*/
            while (result.next()) {
                this.acctNo = result.getString("acctNo");
                this.custId = result.getString("Cid");
                this.type = result.getString("Type");
                this.balance = result.getDouble("Balance");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        } finally {
            connect.close();
        }
    }

    /**
    *sets account number 
    *@param acctNo
    */
    public void setAcctNo(String acctNo) {
        this.acctNo = acctNo;
    }

    /**
     *sets customer id
     * @param custId
     */
    public void setCustId(String custId) {
        this.custId = custId;
    }

    /**
     * sets account type 
     * @param acctType
     */
    public void type(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * sets balance for the account
     * @param balance
     */
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    /**
     * returns account number
     * @return String
     */
    public String getAcctNo() {
        return acctNo;
    }

    /**
     * returns customer id
     * @return String
     */
    public String getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }

    /**
     * returns account type
     * @return String
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * returns account balance
     * @return double
     */
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    /**
     * returns account information into string form
     * @return String 
     */
    public String getAcct() {
        return this.acctNo + " " + this.custId + " " + this.type + " " + this.balance;
    }

    /**
     * returns message set by other methods in class
     * @return String
     */
    public String getMessage(){
        return this.message;
    };

    /**
     * Establishes connection to database
     * @return Connection
     */
    public static Connection acctConnect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Errors: " + e);
        }

        /*Declare new connection*/
        Connection con = null;
        try {

            /*Define connection*/
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ChattDB");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Error: " + e);

        }

        /*Returns connection con*/
        return con;
    }

    /**
     * Uses object account number to get all information from the database
     * where the account number is valid
     */
    public void findDB()  {
        Connection connect = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE acctNo = '" + acctNo + "';";

        try {

            connect = acctConnect();
            statement = connect.createStatement();
            result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            /*Loop through the result to gather all of the information from the 
            row in the database*/
            while (result.next()) {
                this.acctNo = result.getString("acctNo");
                this.custId = result.getString("Cid");
                this.type = result.getString("Type");
                this.balance = result.getDouble("Balance");
            }
            connect.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Error: " + e);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the database accesses the desired account and deposits to that 
     * account. Updates the database. and finally closes the connection. This
     * method throws the sql exception.
     * @param acctNo
     * @param depAmount
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void deposit(String acctNo, double depAmount) throws SQLException {

        Connection connect = acctConnect();
        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = null;
        String sql = "Select balance From Accounts Where acctNO = '" + acctNo + "';";
        String update = null;
        int updateSet = 0;
        double balance = 0.00;
        double newBalance;

        result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        /* retrieves the balance of the current account */
        while (result.next()) {
            balance = result.getDouble("Balance");
        }

        /* updates the balance in this object and the database */
        newBalance = balance + depAmount;
        update = "Update Accounts Set Balance = '" + newBalance + "' Where acctNO = '" + acctNo + "';";
        updateSet = statement.executeUpdate(update);
        this.balance = newBalance;

        /* closes connection */
        connect.close();
    }

    /**
     * Withdraws funds from the current account. Throws an exception 
     * for insufficient funds
     * @param acctNo
     * @param withdrawal
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void withdraw(String acctNo, double withdrawal) throws SQLException, Exception {

        Connection connect = acctConnect();
        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = null;
        String sql = "Select balance From Accounts Where acctNO = '" + acctNo + "';";
        String update = null;
        int updateSet = 0;
        double balance = 0.00;
        double newBalance;

        result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        /* gets balance of the current account from the database */
        while (result.next()) {
            balance = result.getDouble("Balance");
        }

        /* checks to see if the withdrawal amount is more than the balance
        and if so the exception is thrown and an insufficient funds message is 
        set */
        if (balance < withdrawal){
            this.message = "Insufficcient Funds";
            throw new Exception();
        }else{

        /* sets new balance and updates the current database account balance */
        newBalance = balance - withdrawal;
        update = "Update Accounts Set Balance = '" + newBalance + "' Where acctNo = '" + acctNo + "';";
        updateSet = statement.executeUpdate(update);
        this.balance = newBalance;

        }

        /* closes connection to database */
        connect.close();
    }

    /**
     * Transfers funds from one account to another by calling the withdrawal 
     * and deposit methods.
     * @param fromAcct
     * @param toAcct
     * @param transfer
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void transfer(String fromAcct, String toAcct, double transfer) throws SQLException, Exception {

        /* Call withdraw method on from account */
        withdraw(fromAcct, transfer);

        /* deposit to to account */
        deposit(toAcct, transfer);

        /* both methods close their own database connection so it is not necessary to do so here */
    }

    /**
     * Sets up new account for existing customers 
     * @param acctNo
     * @param custID
     * @param type
     * @param balance
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void estabAccount(String custID, String type, double balance) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(custID + " " + type + " " + balance);
        /* Establish connection and update the database with a new row containing the new account info */
        Connection connect = acctConnect();
        Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
        String sql = "Insert Into accounts (Cid, Type, Balance) Values ('" + custID + "', '" + type + "', " + balance + ");";
        System.out.println(sql);
        /* Execute Query and close connection */
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        connect.close();

    }

    public void findDB(String id) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem more clearly . tell us what you are trying to achieve in simple . the code alone never explains clearly

Comment: <td colspan="2">${account.custId}</td> table will not pull up from the database for some reason on the jsp page. I just want to display the table data on the page.

Comment: First, control that you have correct values in the servlet with a `System.out.println` or better using a `logger`. Until they are not there, they won't be in the JSP ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting the Servlet to the jsp page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539073/connecting-the-servlet-to-the-jsp-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Account account = new Account(acctNo);
>     request.setAttribute("account", account);
>     request.getRequestDispatcher("/accountView.jsp").forward(request,
>     response);

Your passing the object of `Account` class alone . if you need to get the value of `custID` in the jsp . you need to set the values in the request with the help of `setters`

```
Account account = new Account();
account.setCustId("value");
```

And you pass the object in the request ,

```
request.setAttribute("account", account);
```

so that it will be available when you are trying to print in the jsp ,

```
<td colspan="2">${account.custId}</td>
```

<sub>I assume your model class `Account` has `setters` and `getters`</sub>

Comment: I placed the account business object there lease in case I missed something